# How to save Data in MongoDB from forms

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, mongodb, mongoose

I have a form. I need to get text from my form to save it in MongoDB.

tweets.ejs:

```
<form method="post" action="/tweets">
<input type="text" id="txt" name="text"/>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Touch me">
</form>
```

Here is my route file tweets.js:

```
var Message = require('models/messages');
exports.get = function(req,res) {
    res.render('tweets')
};
```

I use mongoose schema(models/messages.js):

```
var mongoose = require('../libs/mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var MessageSchema = new Schema({
    message: String,
    date: Date
});
var Message = mongoose.model('Message', MessageSchema);
module.exports = Message;
```

I tried set var m = req.body.text in tweets.js, but I think it's absolutely wrong way

```
exports.post = function(req,res){
    var m = new Message;
    m.message = req.body.text;
    m.save(); }
```

Explain me how to do it right please!

Comment: did you create /tweets POST route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your routes or app file route should be

```
var tweets = require("tweets");
app.post("/tweets", tweets.post);
```

in your tweets.js file

```
var Message = require('models/messages');
exports.post = function(req,res){
console.log(req.body.text)
var msg = {message:req.body.text,date:new Date()};

Message(msg).save(function(error,data){
if (data){
console.log("Save "+ JSON.stringify(data));
res.send({statud:"OK",msg:data})
}
else{
res.send({statud:"Cancel"})
}
});
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I didn't use post in route(I just forgot o_O). Now it saves data, but when I push submit button page can not reload and just freezes. I changed type=button to type=submit

Comment: response was not set, now edit and add res.send().. every REQUEST have RESPONSE ..